# Serving large file with zend framework thats connected to another sftp server

Tags: zend-framework, sftp

I'm using the phpseclib for secure ssh and ftp access. My site is on a webserver, that connects to a different backup server and displays the files and folders, imagine a frontend for a backup on several different servers.

Now I would like them to be able to download a file, but I can't think of a better method than temporarily store the file on the front webserver.

Comment: Would it be possible to use cURL to do the backend to frontend to user file transfer?  I haven't used phpseclib before, but I looked over the docs quickly and didn't see any idea methods for efficiently transferring the data like you want to.

Comment: Well, that would be another question, but I'm not used to either and am a bit lost right now.. Can you point me to some appropiate ressources?

Comment: The reason I was asking if cURL would be usable is because it supports sftp, scp and other secure transfer protocols, and it implements callbacks which you could use to your advantage to efficiently transfer large files from the backup server to the frontend server and then to your client without actually having to store or fully download the entire file first.  You can stream it to the user.  I have an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272611/streaming-a-file-fromftp-and-letting-user-to-download-it-at-the-same-time/10272727#10272727) which demonstrates this with FTP.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I need. Thank you very much, maybe you answer this question with a reference to your other post, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the phpseclib docs and didn't see a great way to transfer a file from one of the backup servers to the frontend server to a client in a fast efficient way without having to fully copy the file from backup server to frontend server before passing it to the client.

Using [cURL](http://php.net/curl) you can use one of its callback functions to serve a download to the client simultaneously while the file is being downloaded from the backup server by cURL.  cURL will support ssh and sftp.  This way, you don't have to have the frontend fully download the file from the backup before being able to send it to the client.

I have shown a similar example of this using the FTP protocol in this answer: [Streaming a file fromFTP and letting user to download it at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272611/streaming-a-file-fromftp-and-letting-user-to-download-it-at-the-same-time/10272727#10272727)

Feel free to ask for more help if you have any questions implementing this solution with SSH and your system.